# How do you fetch an instruction stored at an address pointed to by a register

Tags: c

I'm currently learning ARM assembly and C and I've come upon a problem that I'm not sure how to program. The task is: Write some code in C that fetches the instruction stored at the address pointed to by registers[PC]. It's supposed to be the C code for the fetch-decode-execute cycle.
The code that I have up until now is:

```
int registers[16];
int cpsr;

void set_reg(int reg, int value){
    registers[reg] = value;
}

int get_reg(int reg){
    return registers[reg];
}

int get_cpsr(){
    return cpsr;
}

void my_show_regs(){    
    for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++){        
        printf("register[%02d]: %x\n",i, get_reg(i));    
    }    
    printf("register[%02d]: %x\n",PC, get_reg(PC));
}

void step(){
    //Fetch
```

So to reiterate, what would be the C code that fetches the instruction stored at the address pointed to by registers[PC].

Comment: It looks like you are writing an *emulator*. If that is the case then you need some "program memory" emulated as well (I would say some kind of byte array) then PC will point there.

Comment: that would be `*registers[PC]`. This fetches an int from the address that the array `registers`, indexed by constant or variable `PC`, points to.

Comment: How would you fetch anything from memory?